# How to handle user-defined exception in soap web services or soap faults?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, soapui

I have a requirement where I need to handle the bad_request, etc. other status code which comes when SOAP web service is hit. I understand that SOAP has soap fault so I have tried below piece of code:

```
@WebFault(name = "MissingName", targetNamespace = "http://examples/")
public class MissingName_Exception extends Exception {
  private MissingName faultInfo;
  public MissingName_Exception(String message, MissingName faultInfo) { ... }
  public MissingName_Exception(String message, MissingName faultInfo, 
     Throwable cause) { ... }
  public MissingName getFaultInfo() { ... }
}
```

wsdl :

```
...............
  <message name="MissingName">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:MissingName" /> 
  </message>
  <portType name="HelloWorld">
    <operation name="sayHelloWorld">
      <input message="tns:sayHelloWorld" /> 
      <output message="tns:sayHelloWorldResponse" /> 
      <fault message="tns:MissingName" name="MissingName" /> 
    </operation> 
</portType>
```

Now I need to modify the above code to handle HTTP Status code say 200 as ok, 502 bad gateway, 500 service unavailable etc etc..??

I am newbie to implement `soap webservice`. Please help.

Comment: Please take look at soapui's documentation regarding [assertions](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html)

Comment: @Rao I have re-pharsed my question, I am not looking for assertions, my concern is how to handle Httpstatus code through web service. I hope you can give me better idea of what I am looking for now.